# Randomize numpy.argsort output in case of ties

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, random

I have a numpy array with some elements same as others i.e. there are ties, and I am applying `np.argsort` to find the indices which will sort the array:

```
In [29]: x = [1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2]

In [30]: np.argsort(x)
Out[30]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4])

In [31]: np.argsort(x)
Out[31]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4])
```

As can be seen here, the outputs we get by running `argsort` two times are identical. However, `array([2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4])` is also a completely valid output because some elements in the original array are equal. Can I make argsort return me such "randomized" outputs when there are ties in my array? If not, what is a workaround because I don't want to bias my choice of the lowest values in the array when I am picking them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick would be to add uniform noise in `[0,1)` range and then perform argsort-ing. Adding such a noise forces sorting only within their respective bins and gives randomized sort indices restricted to those bins -

```
(x+np.random.rand(len(x))).argsort()
```